# VF Page export as CSV with asian file name

Tags: visualforce, data-export, csv, character-encoding

I have VF Page and I manage to export it as CSV file. However, when I try to name the file with asian characters (japanese, chinese etc ...) , it does not show.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" cache="true" contentType="text/csv;charset=Shift_JIS;#{!csvName}">{!myData}</apex:page>
```

In controller, I set csvName = "レポート_Test.csv"

The csv file is exported with name  _Test.csv , word レポート is not rendered.
Can anyone help me on this ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the format of the file from **CSV** to **CSV UTF-8**

[image]